# When I'm trying to run Kafka in Ubuntu 16.04 It is throwing with error?

Tags: apache-kafka

Here is the command i.e I'm typing from terminal

```
 sudo /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties
Could not find or load main class kafka.Kafka
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear which version of Kafka you've used, but I can assure you that the latest version is working for me in Ubuntu (via Docker)

try to cd into the parent folder of bin and config first

Also, try [installing Kafka from APT](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html)